# Select folder control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, select, controls, directory

I would like to add a control to my ASP.NET 4.0 project for the user to search select their local directory and select a folder. Does this exist?

I don't want to upload the folder, just select it and then manipulate the resulitng string